# How to force Python 3.9 to compile using OpenSSL 1.1.1 correctly in Centos 7

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl, centos7, pyopenssl

Running Centos 7 and have both Python 3.6 and 3.9 installed as altinstalls.

I've installed openssl 1.1.1 and can verify that by using "openssl version" but every time I try to install a new module with Python 3.9 I get SSL errors.

`[root@server Modules]# openssl version   OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021`

`[root@server Modules]# python3 -m pip install meraki   WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/meraki/   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/meraki/   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/meraki/   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/meraki/   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/meraki/   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/meraki/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/meraki/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement meraki (from versions: none)   ERROR: No matching distribution found for meraki   WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 23.1.2 is available.   You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

I also navigated to /usr/src/Python-3.9.6/Modules and edited the Setup file to uncomment the SSL lines.

[python Setup file with SSL lines uncommented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO0FB.png)

But I think that the location that the Setup file points to doesn't have any ssl files in it, so the location variable might need to change.. but I don't know how to find the actual location of my SSL install.

Here are the outputs of which ssl and which openssl

`[root@server Modules]# which ssl   /usr/bin/which: no ssl in  (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/cloud/.local/bin:/home/cloud/bin)`

`[root@server Modules]# which openssl   /usr/bin/openssl`

I have tried re-installing OpenSSL which I expected to force the OpenSSL into a location that Python 3.9 could find it. I saw no change in Python 3.9's behavior when I try calling pip install.

I also uncommented the SSL lines in the Setup file, expecting that to "turn on" the SSL capabilities of Python 3.9 - but again I saw no change in the behavior of PY3.9.

I also tried running these lines based on another stackoverflow answer I found:

export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $(pkg-config --cflags openssl11)"
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $(pkg-config --libs openssl11)"

but got this output:

`[root@server Python-3.9.6]# export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $(pkg-config --cflags openssl11)"   Package openssl11 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` openssl11.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'openssl11' found`

The output instructed me to "add the directory containing `openssl11.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH" but I don't know how to find the location of 'openssl11.pc' or how I would add it to the env. variable.

Comment: *I've installed openssl 1.1.1*  You **didn't** overwrite the OS-supplied `/usr/bin/openssl` binary in Centos 7 with a 1.1.1 version you compiled yourself, did you?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I may have - I used these instructions https://gist.github.com/Bill-tran/5e2ab062a9028bf693c934146249e68c

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have other tools running in this server off of Python2 and Python3.6 and those are all still working, would overriding the OS-supplied openssl be the cause of Python3.9 not working?

Comment: Throw your Linux install away.  RHEL/Centos 7 installs OpenSSL 1.0.2, **and the OS depends on that**.  Those instructions have you overwrite components of the OS install of OpenSSL 1.0.2.  Anyone who posts instructions on how to "upgrade" an OS-installed component to a binary-incompatible later version - for example, by compiling and installing into `/usr` - is an idiot who's never been responsible for maintaining a system long-term.  What do you think is going to happen the next time you run `yum update`?  It's likely to overwrite your "upgrade" and break things further.

Comment: The way to install OpenSSL 1.1.1 on RHEL/Centos 7 is `yum install openssl11`.  The failures you're experiencing are what happens when you "upgrade" like that misguided moron's instructions told you to.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and I solved it by installing `openssl-devel` or `openssl-dev` package from the package installer (yum in your case I guess).